# Confusion whilst drawing query search tree?

Tags: prolog, logic, search-tree

We are working with the following knowledge base:

```
house_elf(dobby).

witch(hermione).
witch('McGonagall').
witch(rita_skeeter).

magic(X):- house_elf(X).
magic(X):- wizard(X).
magic(X):- witch(X).
```

The question of the exercise was:

> Which of the following queries are satisfied? Where relevant, give all the variable instantiations that lead to success.

I am stuck on question 5:

```
?- magic(Hermione).
```

> Also draw the search tree for the query magic(Hermione) .

Although I understand what is kind of happening with the  query, I am getting confused in how to draw a query search tree. Also the fact that that in our query (Hermione) is a variable is also leading to more confusion?

Would you please mind guiding me and explaining what goes on when this query is proposed to Prolog?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Atoms versus Variables**

A string starting with a capital letter, like, `Hermione`, is a variable. If it starts with a lower case letter, like `hermione`, it's an atom (think of it as a "constant" as in other languages). Or if it's in single quotes, like `'Hermione'`, it is also an atom.

The following is a fact:

```
witch(hermione).
```

It could be read: *`hermione` is a `witch`*. How it's really read (or more specifically, what it's semantic meaning is) is up to you, the programmer.

If I query this fact at the Prolog prompt, it will succeed:

```
| ?- witch(hermione).

yes
```

(Note, this is `gprolog`, so it yields `yes`. I think SWI Prolog would say `true`, but they both mean "success".)

I can also query with a variable, and Prolog will tell you what instantiations (settings) of the variable will make it true:

```
| ?- witch(Hermione).

Hermione = hermione ? ;

Hermione = 'McGonagall' ? ;

Hermione = rita_skeeter

(1 ms) yes
```

Remember: `Hermione` is a variable, and `hermione` is an atom. They are NOT the same thing. So the variable, `Hermione` can have any one of the above values to make `witch(Hermione)` be true. You could just as well queried, `witch(Fred)` and gotten the same results above with `Fred` instead of `Hermione`.

**Basic Predicate Logic**

Now let's look at the predicate, `magic/1` (the `1` here indicates the *arity*, or how may arguments `magic` has):

```
magic(X):- house_elf(X).
magic(X):- wizard(X).
magic(X):- witch(X).
```

Semantically, you can read this as, *`X` is `magic` if `X` is a `house_elf`, OR `X` is `magic` if `X` is a `wizard`, OR `X` is `magic` if `X` is a `witch`*.

If we then query:

```
| ?- magic(Hermione).
```

Prolog will attempt to find out what instantiations of `Hermione` will make this succeed and tell you what those values are. In all of your facts and predicates, it will find the first match at the clause `magic(X):- house_elf(X).`, using `Hermione` as the variable in place of `X`, and it will find that if `Hermione = dobby`, then `house_elf(Hermione)` will be true, and, therefore, `magic(Hermione)` will be true. It will show that as the first solution: `Hermione = dobby`:

```
| ?- magic(Hermione).

Hermione = dobby ? ;
```

By pressing `;` here (or SPACE), Prolog will try to find the next solution, and in this case it won't find the next success until it goes to the next clause, `magic(X):- wizard(X).`. Assuming you have some facts for `wizard/1`, it will succeed on those. If `wizard/1` isn't defined in your facts or predicates, then you'll get an existence error from Prolog stating that it doesn't know what `wizard/1`. Prolog will keep walking through your predicate clauses, looking for ways to make it succeed, and telling you what value (instantiation) of `Hermione` will make it so until it has exhausted all the cases. Then it will finally stop.

I'll leave it as an exercise to figure out the search tree, but do a Google search on "Prolog search tree" to find some [good examples](http://www.fb10.uni-bremen.de/anglistik/ling/ws08/intro-cl-materials/prolog-search-tree.pdf). I assume you have Prolog interpreter in which you can enter your code and play with queries to see what happens. You can enable tracing (enter `trace.`) to see some details on what Prolog is doing on queries as well. All of these methods can help understanding of some aspects of Prolog operation.